# Differential Manipulations

Tags: calculus

Let's say you have the below differential.

$dz = \left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{y}dx + \left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_{x}dy $

What exactly does $dx = 0$ imply?  I originally thought it would imply the below.

$dz(x_{0}, y) = \left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_{x} (x_{0}, y) dy $

where $x_{0}$ is an undefined constant.

However, I saw a proof in a book where the below occured which seems to imply x could potentially vary depending on other functional relationships.

$dz]_{x} = \left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_{x}dy$

Comment: $dx$ can’t be zero because together with $dy$ they are a basis for a vector space

Comment: This type of manipulation is used heavily in Thermodynamics and can be used to prove the triple product rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$dz$ is the total differential, $\frac{\delta z(x,y)}{\delta x}dx$ is the partial differential with respect to $x$. $dx=0$ means the infinitesimal deviation in x-direction is zero. That means you consider only the infinitesimal deviation of the function $z$ in y-direction.

There is no further restriction. You can calculate the derivative of the function $z(x,y)$ at a point: $z(x_0,y_0)$, and for the curves $z(x,y)$, $z(x_0,y)$, $z(x,y_0)$. $dx=0$ alone does change only the direction of the derivative, not the starting figure.